# connection not closed after timeout exception

Tags: java, resources, try-catch, httpurlconnection

when retrieving a file I can't close the connection in case of timeout, when the timeout exception throws, i want to skip the file and pass to the next file.
.... java.net.sockettimeoutexception : connect timed out... which is repeated on the same file,
I want to ignore the file when the first error is thrown

```
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
       
    try{  con.addRequestProperty("Accept", "app/json");

      con.addRequestProperty("Authorization", jsonParams);

      con.setConnectTimeout(timeoutConnection); 

      int repCode = con.getResponseCode(); 

      String output= IOUtils.toString(con.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");

      return new file(repCode, output);

      } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {

                        System.err.print(e.getMessage());

                        con.getInputStream().close(); //close the connection

                        throw new ConnectTimeoutException(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: No, you can try `con.disconnect();` but it doesn't guaranty that the connection will actually be disconnected.

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work :(